# How to run vbs in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

I'm trying to run this vbscript in Internet Explorer, but it doesnt seem to work. It works when I make it .vbs file and double click, but not on the browser.

```
Dim strWebsite

strWebsite = "www.site.org"

If PingSite( strWebsite ) Then
    WScript.Echo "Web site " & strWebsite & " is up and running!"
Else
    WScript.Echo "Web site " & strWebsite & " is down!!!"
End If


Function PingSite( myWebsite )
    Dim intStatus, objHTTP

    Set objHTTP = CreateObject( "WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1" )

    objHTTP.Open "GET", "http://" & myWebsite & "/", False
    objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MyApp 1.0; Windows NT 5.1)"

    On Error Resume Next

    objHTTP.Send
    intStatus = objHTTP.Status

    On Error Goto 0

    If intStatus = 200 Then
        PingSite = True
    Else
        PingSite = False
    End If

    Set objHTTP = Nothing
End Function
```

What is the correct way to do that ?

Comment: why is this tagged `javascript`? Can you show your html code where you're importing this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hot from the MS press: [VBScript is no longer supported in IE11 edge mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn384057%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (as you probably knew, other browsers (that don't run on an MS renderer) didn't run vbs anyway)

The 'correct' way is to translate this to javascript (no seriously, you can currently still mock about but it's clearly very deprecated and advised to update old code now), which isn't that hard since this technique originated at MS. You'd still do a head-request and check the status-no.

This should get you started: [HTTP HEAD Request in Javascript/Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333634/http-head-request-in-javascript-ajax)

**EDIT** (addressing your comment):
Don't count on reliably setting the `useragent` though (that, like the above script, seems more a thing of the past):

- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=627942
- [Set a request header in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268673/set-a-request-header-in-javascript)
- [XMLHttpRequest and setRequestHeader in IE returns an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527357/xmlhttprequest-and-setrequestheader-in-ie-returns-an-error)

**EDIT2:**
I see/think you want somehow to differentiate your app: `MyApp 1.0;` (in the logs perhaps?). If that's the case, you might want to add some custom headers instead:
[How can I add a custom HTTP header to ajax request with js or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686827/how-can-i-add-a-custom-http-header-to-ajax-request-with-js-or-jquery)

Also, most server-logs (by default) pick up on the `GET`-String, you might want to use/add-to that (so you wouldn't have to change the log-format if your custom header wouldn't show up)?

Comment: Yeah but, is it possible to change the useragent ? thats why Im struggling with that.

Comment: Yeah. If edit 2 was working on IE, that would be awesome, but dramatically, these ajax post methods doesnt work in IE.

Answer (score 2):

```
Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")

oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", "http://..................", False
oXMLHTTP.Send

If oXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
'"website ok"
End If
```